# Parsing - Adding a capturing group

Tags: r, regex, pcre, capturing-group

I am attempting to use a fairly complex REGEX expression (see REGEX101 demos below), which I amended slightly from one created by an expert on this site. It parses specific patterns of log events:

- **1**EXE_IN**1**EXE_CO**2**CONTENT_ACCESS**3**CONTENT_ACCESS

These log sequences will always begin with a random selection of `EXE_IN` or `EXE_CO` events, preceded sequence numbers. These selections can be any number, in any order. In this case, we just have two `EXE` events but this may be 200. Or 1. Note that there is a sequence number and we need to capture it.

The second part of the sequence will always be a series of digit-prefaced `CONTENT.ACCESS` events. Again from 1 to infinity in length.

The following demo shows a working example and probably conveys the concept better than I can : [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/m4UD0j/27)

It nicely captures a full match, sequence number, and event in separate groups.

I need to add a timestamp to the pattern (after the sequence number, with a preceding underscore), and then parse this event log e.g.

- 1_11/08/2014 23:03EXE_IN1_11/08/2014 23:03EXE_CO2_12/08/2014 09:17CONTENT_ACCESS3_13/08/2014 09:17CONTENT_ACCESS

I need to capture the timestamps as well.

I attempted to adjust the regex expression, with mixed results. Please see this demo: [demo2](https://regex101.com/r/m4UD0j/28)

Ideally I'd like to see something like this for each event:

```
Match n
Full match  266-308 `2_12/08/2014 09:17CONTENT_ACCESS`
Group 1. 266-267    `2`
Group 2. 268-284    `12/08/2014 09:17`
Group 3. 284-308    `CONTENT_ACCESS`
```

I hope you can help me. REGEX101 pcre testing is sufficient *(for the record, I am using perl-compatible str_match_all_perl function in R)*.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @UnbearableLightness, thanks for the edits. Let me know if you happen on a solution. Cheers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(\d+)_(.*?)(EXE_CO|EXE_IN|CONTENT_ACCESS)`

https://regex101.com/r/EHHcKm/1

Due to comments it was changed to `(?:\G(?!^)(?(?=\d+_\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}(?:EXE_CO|EXE_IN))(?<!\d_\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}CONTENT_ACCESS))|(?=(?:\d+_\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}(?:EXE_CO|EXE_IN))+(?:\d+_\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}CONTENT_ACCESS)+))(\d+)_(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\s\d{2}\:\d{2})(EXE_CO|EXE_IN|CONTENT_ACCESS)`

https://regex101.com/r/EHHcKm/3

Ans also another version, which is shorter
`(?:\G(?!^)(?(?=\d+_.{16}(?:EXE_CO|EXE_IN))(?<!\d_.{16}CONTENT_ACCESS))|(?=(?:\d+_.{16}(?:EXE_CO|EXE_IN))+(?:\d+_.{16}CONTENT_ACCESS)+))(\d+)_(.{16})(EXE_CO|EXE_IN|CONTENT_ACCESS)`

https://regex101.com/r/EHHcKm/4

And even more shorter `(?:\G(?!^)(?(?=\d+_.{16}E)(?<!S))|(?=(?:\d+_.{16}(?:EXE_CO|EXE_IN))+\d+_.{16}C))(\d+)_(.{16})(EXE_CO|EXE_IN|CONTENT_ACCESS)`

https://regex101.com/r/EHHcKm/5

And super short `(?:\G|(?=\d+_.{16}E.*CON))(\d+)_(.*?)(EXE_CO|EXE_IN|CONTENT_ACCESS)`

https://regex101.com/r/EHHcKm/8

Comment: Hi there, thanks for responding. I realise I may not have been explicit here, but the string is formed of two parts. The first part must start with either an EXE_CO event or an EXE_IN event, or a random selection of these events. The second part must be present and can be one or more instances of a CONTENT_ACCESS event. It is this grouping I am looking for.

Comment: So in this example... 1_11/08/2014 23:03EXE_IN1_11/08/2014 23:03EXE_CO2_12/08/2014 09:17CONTENT_ACCESS3_13/08/2014 09:17CONTENT_ACCESS   we can only have EXE's on the left and CONTENT_ACCESS's on the right. They must be together but cannot be mixed up. Please let me know if you need any more clarification.

Comment: As I understand you need something like this `(?(?<=S)(\d+)_(.{16})(CONTENT_ACCESS)|(?(?<=O|N)(\d+)_(.{16})(EXE_CO|EXE_IN|CONTENT_ACCESS)|(\d+)_(.{16})(EXE_CO|EXE_IN)))` https://regex101.com/r/EHHcKm/2 . But I highly not recommend you to do that, it's much easier to analyze everything in R, than try to do that in Regex

Comment: Hi there, Good call with the timestamp capture. It is a better and simpler capture than mine. Your answer is closer but the groups do not capture very cleanly. I still very much appreciate your efforts. I was just wondering if you might be able to amend the example here: [link](https://regex101.com/r/m4UD0j/27). This works but does without the timestamps. Or some guidance on the R code may help. Sorry if I am asking too much.

Comment: @Funtboy I've updated the answer. I still don't understand how you want to work on `3CONTENT_ACCESS1EXE_IN2EXE_CO3CONTENT_ACCESS`, but I've done it just like it works in your link. Also optimized it to super short version, which should be much faster.

Comment: Outstanding! This is what I need for this case. Just to clarify what I am looking for: For the sake of argument, let's replace the EXE_IN strings (including the  sequence number and timestamp) with *a*, EXE_CO by *b*, and the CONTENT_ACCESS with *c*. So what I want parsed is a two part string. The first half can be a random collection of a's and b's (or a single a or b), and the second half a sequence of c's (or just one). Valid examples: ac  aaaaaaaaaaac ababababccc accccccccc bccccc ababbbbaaaacc.

Comment: First of all, thanks again for this. You have answered my question. I actually have a slightly broader question, based on what you have done here. I am not sure whether I need to ask a new question or not. In essence, if you take the *abc* example above, I would like to also identify strings such as these (as separate parses). Parse 1, a sequence of c's then ab combo:  *ccccccabababa*. Parse 2,  ab combos then cd combos e.g. *ababaabaacdcdcddddd*. Parse 3,  abc then xyz combos e.g.  *abcdcaaaacxyzzzzxxy*. My REGEX skills are still not up to doing this myself. New question?

Comment: @Funtboy I think yes, it is not actually connected to this question in my opinion.